# Laravel 7 relationship query data not working

Tags: php, laravel

I would like to query companies name through employees. Why didnt get any result?
It not give any error.

Companies model

```
    public function employees() {
        return $this->hasMany(Employees::class);
    }
```

Employees model

```
   
    public function companies() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Companies::class);
    }
```

Employees controller

```
     public function createIndex() {

        $employees = Employees::all();

        return view('employees.create', [
            'employees' => $employees
        ]);
    }
```

Where i like to query

```
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="company">Company: </label>
                <select name="company" class="form-control">
                @foreach($employees as $employe)
                    <option selected>Choose...</option>

                    @foreach($employe->companies as $company)
                        <option id="company">{{ $company->name }}</option>
                    @endforeach
                @endforeach
                </select>
            </div>
```

This is the migrations for tables

```
        Schema::create('companies', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email');
            $table->string('logo');
            $table->string('website');
            $table->timestamps();
        });

        Schema::create('employees', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('fname');
            $table->string('lname');
            $table->string('email');
            $table->string('phone');
            $table->bigInteger('companies_id')->unsigned();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->foreign('companies_id')->references('id')->on('companies')
                      ->onDelete('cascade');
        });
```

Comment: Could you please share your migration of both company and employee table?

Comment: Yes i added to it

Comment: add foreign_key column  $this->belongsTo('App\Companies', 'foreign_key'); then check what happen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please provide the foreign key to your relation ...

```
 public function companies()
 { return $this->belongsTo(Companies::class,'companies_id'); }
```

this relation means that the employee has only one company (belongs To one company)

so you can't iterate over it!

in this line:

```
@foreach($employe->companies as $company)
                    <option id="company">{{ $company->name }}</option>
                @endforeach
```

employe->companies will return only one object ..
if you want to show all companies as options, pass $allCompany like:

```
 public function createIndex() {

        $employees = Employees::all();
   $compnanies = Companies::all();
        return view('employees.create', [
            'employees' => $employees,'compnanies'=> $compnanies
        ]);
    }
```

then you can iterate $compnanies in your view

Comment: So nice explained answer.